# How store access keys on BB10 Webworks

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am using twitter oAuth in a app, each time of app starts asking for authorisation, but I want a single time authentication to use timeline and other things for that I want to store access tokens, How is it possible.
Thanks in advance..! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use localStorage for this. There's a simple guide with samples here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

On other platforms (Android), I wouldn't recommend this since the app's sandbox can be easily compromised on some devices. On BB10 though, the app file can't be obtained by rooting the device (since it is secure) and the sandbox can't be compromised. If you're extra worried about security, run the token through an algorithm to 'encrypt' the token before saving it to localStorage. Since the code in your app can't be compromised (again, secure platform), that algorithm is safe and secret.

Also, BB10 affords you 25 MB of space in localStorage, which makes it a really nice container for dynamic things. Local Storage will persist when you close the app and open it.

Again, this is not a best practice for all platforms, since on some platforms the app or it's sandbox can be compromised such that someone could get your API keys or tokens just by extracting your app file. But it should be safe on BB10.

Good luck!

John

*Note, response is my own and is not endorsed by my employer.*